# Angular 6: error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

I have textarea which allow user to submit comments, I want to grab the date on time the comment is submitted, and save to json together with comment added :

after comment is submitted in json file I would like to have something like this:

```
 "comment": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "Michael Ross",
      "city": "New York USA",
      "date": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
      "task_id": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et lig"
    }
]
```

Problem: Right now when comment is submitted I have the following: no date is displayed:

```
 "comment": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "Michael Ross",
      "city": "New York USA",
      "task_id": 1,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet enim. Etiam ullamcorper. Suspendisse a pellentesque dui, non felis. Maecenas malesuada elit lectus felis, malesuada ultricies. Curabitur et lig"
    }
]
```

Here is what I have tried so far to grab the date from entered comment.

HTML :

```
<form class="add-comments" [formGroup]="addForm" (keyup.enter)="addComments()">
      <input type="hidden" id="localTime" name="localTime">
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" placeholder="Add comments" formControlName="description" id="description"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is method on compoents ts.

```
 addComments(task_id) {
    const formData = this.addForm.value;
    formData.task_id = task_id;
    this.userService.addComments(formData)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.comments.push(this.addForm.value);
    });
    const date = new Date();
    const d = date.getUTCDate();
    const day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
    const m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
    const year = date.getUTCFullYear();
    const h = date.getUTCHours();
    const hour = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h;
    const mi = date.getUTCMinutes();
    const minute = (mi < 10) ? '0' + mi : mi;
    const sc = date.getUTCSeconds();
    const second = (sc < 10) ? '0' + sc : sc;
    const loctime = month + day + hour + minute + year + '.' + second;

    document.getElementById('localTime').value = loctime;

  }
```

Unfortunatelly when I submit the comment , I get the following error

```
ERROR in src/app/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts(75,21): error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'string | number' and 'string | number'.
src/app/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts(77,42): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

what do I need to change to get what I want??

Comment: What is the format of `loctime` inside "compoents ts"?

Comment: `const loctime = month + day + hour + minute + year + '.' + second;` I dd it this way but am not sure if its right that is why I needed some help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code

```
const loctime = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;
// output "2018-10-27T10:26:32"
```

Instead of using Javascript Way, try to use Angular way

```
<input type="hidden" id="localTime" name="localTime" formControlName="localTime">

this. addForm.get('localTime').setValue(loctime);
```

Note: we need to use back-tick(``) instead of single quote ('').

Comment: Let me check I will brb :)

Comment: after changing as you recommended I get the following error: `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: using this value, r u applying datepipe?. You can't apply string to datepipe. First Convert to Date (YYYY-MM-DD), then apply pipe

Comment: here is my repo  https://github.com/throne1986/profile/blob/master/src/app/user-profile/user-profile.component.ts  , can you show me how to convert to date ?  am strugling to figure this out

Comment: its wrong const loctime = '${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}'; Correct is const loctime = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;  instead of single quote, use back-stick.

Comment: instead of single quote, use back-stick (``)

Comment: That works as expected thanks bro, can you put it as answer for future reference and I will accept that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182632/discussion-between-user9964622-and-suresh-kumar-ariya).

Comment: Now when I add comments , displays comments and date but afteer refresh date is gone , what do I need to change to save the data  to json file , now this is what I have in json file  after submit : `{
      "id": 3,
      "localTime": null,
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor" }`